# How would I query a SQL database to find a date that a record first appeared?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with these three fields...  date, mail_date, and dealer_id.  I would like to know if there is a way to find out which dealer_id AND mail_date did not have a date in the table until 5 days after the mail_date.

Comment: How is the date stored? As a timestamp? Or as mysql date()

Comment: So you're not looking to compare male_date and date, you're looking for details about when date was populated?

Comment: @PhilCross It's stored as a mysql date()

Comment: @Goat_CO Exactly, so if that dealer_id + mail_date had a date populated before 5 days.  I don't want to know about.

Comment: You can't compare data that isn't there, to my knowledge there is no change-log in mysql that you could access to find that detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT date, mail_date, dealer_id 
FROM tableName 
WHERE DATE_DIFF(mail_date, date)>=5
```

I think thats correct! try it and see. If it doesn't, comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

Select mail_date, dealer_id from table1 where date not between mail_date and mail_date+5;